# Keras Parameters for Convolutional Net

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I'm looking at Keras' example for convolutional neural networks. (See https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_cnn.py for example.) However, I cannot figure out what they mean by the "maxlen" parameter. Would it have something to do with padding? It isn't the maximum number of features; they have a max_features parameter for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `maxlen` parameter is the length of your text samples in words.

In the Keras code example you have these settings:

```
# set parameters:
max_features = 5000
maxlen = 400
...
embedding_dims = 50
```

This means you have a vocabulary of 5000 words, each of these words are embedded into a feature vector with 50 dimensions and each of your text samples can be 400 words long.

Indirectly this also has a relation to padding when you have text samples that are shorter than 400 words. Then you have to pad these to a length of 400.

For 1D-ConvNets for text classification see also this paper and this blog post:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5882

http://www.wildml.com/2015/11/understanding-convolutional-neural-networks-for-nlp/